# Adding/removing items from a QT layout

Tags: qt

I'm trying to add some items dynamically to a vertical layout, so I'm creating a new horizontal layout, adding a label and push button to that, then adding this to the vertical layout using addLayout, but it doesn't seem to be happening correctly.

If i put a breakpoint in and go through the 'this' object's children, I find the vertical layout object, and it has the push button and label as children - no horizontal layout object to be seen, but in the GUI it is being layed out like it's in a horizontal layout (yes the naming convention here is bad).

```
QHBoxLayout *AA = new QHBoxLayout;
QLabel *BB = new QLabel;
QPushButton *CC = new QPushButton;
AA->addWidget(BB);
AA->addWidget(CC);
ui->verticalLayout->addLayout(AA);
```

I then try to remove the buttons from the horizontal layout and remove the horizontal layout and delete them, but depending upon how I do it, it either doesn't work or crashes.

```
QHBoxLayout *a1 = ui->verticalLayout->layout()->findChild<QHBoxLayout*>();
QPushButton *a2 = ui->verticalLayout->findChild<QPushButton*>();
QPushButton *a3 = a1->findChild<QPushButton*>();
//(a2 and a3 are both null, a1 returns an object)
```

So my question is how do I add items dynamically to a horizontal layout then add this to an existing layout, and then later iterate through this to remove them? (One unfortunate thing I've found with Qt thus far is tutorials or 'how tos' for dynamic layouts is completely lacking, most things I've tried have came from posts on SO).

Comment: When I had a problem a little like yours, the advice from SO was not to mix layouts done in Qt-Creator with adding things dynamically (which it seems like your doing).  I never got my code to work and ended up having the whole gui created in code in order to do what I wanted to do.

Comment: Just switched to creating the whole interface dynamically and its working! Thanks for the advice. :)

Comment: You're welcome. I was kind of hoping you'd find a way to do it, but I'm glad you're up and running.